# how to releasing locks of vdisks from citrix PVS console using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am a citrix admin, i am trying to do some automation for managing the provisioning server but i am unable to find the power shell command to release a vdisk locks from the citrix PVS console,please help me if any possible way to achieve this.